# Does the Orion Context Broker provide a query or filter for structured attributes?

Tags: fiware-orion

In the link below is mentioned that orion provide support for structured attributes, but is not clear if the orion suport query or filters over theses attributes.

Here's [STRUCTURED VALUES FOR ATTRIBUTES](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.1/user/structured_attribute_valued/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, filters also work for structured attributes. They are described in the [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) document, in particular in section "Simple Query Language".

You can check some examples in [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/fermingalan/orion-context-broker-20180928) slide 61:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be great if you could +1 on the anwser. It is not to feed my ego ;) but to let other users to know the answer is correct and valid. Thanks!